# Can JSP page remember the old object it had ?

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications, servlets

I'm moving from :

```
JSP1->JSP2-JSP3-JSP1
```

In **JSP1** - the admin screen , I have the object which stores the data of the `Administrator` : this is **adminPage.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>System Administrator Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>


<h1>Hello ${name.firstName} ${name.lastName} , You've logged in successfully!</h1>
<h1>
Please choose one of the following options
</h1>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Add a new employee to the bank system</legend> 
  <form action="blablabla">     <!-- THAT ONE forwards to a servlet that's called Admin1.java -->
    <a href="adminAdds1">Press here to continue</a>  
  </form>
</fieldset>


<!-- NOTE THE FORWARDS TO THE SERVLETS -->


<fieldset>
  <legend>Add a new manager to the bank system</legend>
  <form action="blablabla">  <!-- THAT ONE forwards to a servlet that's called Admin2.java -->
    <a href="adminAdds2">Press here to continue</a>
  </form>
</fieldset>

</body></html>
```

Picture:

[image]

Then I go to the next page - **JSP2** which is **adminAddNewEmployee.jsp** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>System Administrator Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>


<h1>Registration Page for Administrator!</h1>
<h1>
Add a new employee to the bank system
</h1>

<!-- Admin adds a new employee -->

<fieldset>
  <legend>Registration</legend>
  <form action="adminOperation1"> 
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
    Last name : <input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
    Address   : <input type="text" name="address"><br>
    ID-number : <input type="text" name="idnumber"><br>
    User-Name : <input type="text" name="userName"><br>
    Password  : <input type="text" name="password"><br>
    Status    : <input type="text" name="status"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
  </form>
</fieldset>

</body></html>
```

Looks like that :

[image]

And I , the administrator , add a new manager to the system .

Then I reach here - to **JSP3** which is : **adminSuccess.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Database has been updated successfully!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Congratulations , Database has been updated successfully for the following Manager!</h1>
<h2>Manager's first-Name: ${name.firstName}</h2>
<h2>Manager's last-Name: ${name.lastName}</h2>
<h2>Manager's address: ${name.address}</h2>
<h2>Manager's password: ${name.password}</h2>
<h2>Manager's user-Name: ${name.userName}</h2>
<h2>Manager's id-Number: ${name.idnumber }</h2>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Continue to Admin's transactions page</legend>
  <form action="blablabla"> 
    <a href="adminAdds3">Press here to continue</a>
  </form>
</fieldset>

</body></html>
```

Picture :

[image]

Now , I want to go back to the mother-base , e.g **JSP1** , which is **adminPage.jsp** , so I've added a servlet :

```
/**
 * Servlet implementation class Admin3
 */
@WebServlet("/adminAdds3")
public class Admin3 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/results/adminPage.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }


}
```

In order to go back to **JSP1** , but then I get this :

[image]

So ,instead my **original** Admin , Jack Reacher , I get David Bowie.....

the old admin is not stored .

How can I fix this ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the session variables(name and id of user who has looged in ) when you login your acount and when ever you require this id and username you can get it by accesing session varialbes..
this will defintely solve your problem

or

try by changing name of text box from firstname to first_name on jsp2